# Template argument deduction failing for const pointers

Tags: c++, template-argument-deduction

I don't understand why template argument deduction fails in this case:

```
template<class Iterator> void
f(Iterator x, const Iterator y) {}

int main()
{
    const int* cpi;
    int* pi;
    f(pi,cpi);
}
```

Why does `Iterator` does not deduce to `int*` for the second parameter?

What would be the most idiomatic declaration for `f`?

Comment: `const int*` is a pointer to a constant int. Since `Iterator` is deduced as "pointer to an int" in the first parameter, `const Iterator` is a "constant pointer to an int", which is a different type. try `int* const` instead for cp1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a trait to check if the iterator is an iterator over const values.

```
#include <iterator>    // iterator_traits
#include <type_traits> // is_const_v, remove_pointer_t, enable_if_t

template<typename T>
struct is_const_iterator {
    // Define a pointer type to the type iterated over. Something already a pointer
    // will still be a pointer
    using pointer = typename std::iterator_traits<T>::pointer;

    // Remove the pointer part from the type and check for constness.
    static const bool value = std::is_const_v<std::remove_pointer_t<pointer>>;
};

// Helper variable template to simplify the use of the above.
template<class T>
inline constexpr bool is_const_iterator_v = is_const_iterator<T>::value;
```

SFINAE use of `is_const_iterator_v`

```
template<class It, class CIt, std::enable_if_t<is_const_iterator_v<CIt>, int> = 0>
void f(It x, CIt y) {
    //for(; x != y; ++x) std::cout << *x << '\n';
}
```

Alternatively, if your function doesn't have other overloads (does not need SFINAE), you can use `static_assert` to make it even clearer for the user:

```
template<class It, class CIt>
void f(It x, CIt y) {
    static_assert(is_const_iterator_v<CIt>, "Arg 2 must be a const iterator");
    //for(; x != y; ++x) std::cout << *x << '\n';
}
```

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int values[]{1, 2};

    int* pi = values;
    const int* cpi = values + std::size(values);

    std::vector<int> v{3, 4};

    f(pi, cpi);
    f(v.begin(), v.cend());
    // f(pi, pi);             // error, pi is non-const
    // f(v.begin(), v.end()); // error v.end() is non-const
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Iterator can be either `int *` or `const int *`. The qualifier const of the second function parameter means either `int * const` or `const int * const`.

Comment: Ah ok I understand. But then the only way to get around it is to declare a second template parameter? I was hoping there was a more constrained way (yet not too heavy) to get around...

Comment: @Bérenger A simple way is to introduce a second template argument like class Iterator2.

Comment: Yes I know but then there is no constrain on this `Iterator2` class, whereas it should be the const version of `Iterator`